# How to reuse event added page in cluster.task? (do not close page after task, and want to reuse it)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

In `cluster.task`, I added some event like `framenavigated` with complex logic.

I use puppeteer-cluster in my API server, when request get in, adding in the queue, and workers do the job sequencely.

But every time request comes, `framenavigated` event register again with use of cpu.

How can I reuse `event added page` in workers?

---

I don't want to close `event added page` in `cluster.task`, and reuse in next request.
Is it possible?

if can't, I would like to customize your library not to open/close pages at every request, would you please point where is the part of cluster.task's page open/close part?

---

EDIT : smaple code!

```
await cluster.task(async ({ page, data : url }) => {       
    /* 
        DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS EVENT REGISTERING JOB WITH EVERY REQUEST.
        ONLY WANT TO DO THIS ONCE, AND REUSE WITH NEXT `queue`, `execute` REQEUST COMES.
    */
    page.on("framenavigated", async () =>  {
            // Some complex job here.        
    })



    /* 
        WANT TO DO WITH EVERY REQUEST WITH REUSING EVENT REGISTERED `PAGE` 
        example : page jobs, I want to do this with every requests comes.
    */
    await page.goto(url)
    console.log(page.url())
})
```

I just want to reuse `page` object in `cluster.task` with `framenavigated` event registered.

Thank you. @ThomasDondorf

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want to reuse pages? Can you provide example code showing your issue?

Comment: [HERE](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/issues/191#issuecomment-521527018) I made a sample code!